# Check size of multi-line textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox

I've been trying for hours to figure this out.
Why in a multi-line textbox asp control, I have a limit of 140 characters but sometimes I can input 141 or 142 characters, especially with the use of the enter key?

Here's my code

```
function CheckSize(o, size) {
    if (o != null) {
        var s = o.value.length;
        if (s > size) {
            debugger;
            alert('Lamentamos mas foi atingido o limite máximo para o texto a introduzir.\nSugerimos que introduza um texto com menos de ' + size + ' caracteres.\nAgradecemos a sua compreensão.');
            // alert(resources.error_reachedMaxNumberOfChars.replace("{0}",String(size)));
            var trim = o.value.trim();
            o.value = trim.substring(0, size - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you relate this function to your markup? Can you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: Side note: `substring()` does not take the character that is in the position designated by the second parameter, so you don't need the `- 1` . . . this should be what you are looking for: `o.value = trim.substring(0, size);`

Comment: Also, what browser are you using?  IE8 and below don't support the `trim()` method for strings.  That would break the logic as it was trying to trim the value in the textarea.

Comment: Hint: Use jQuery... it will make your life much easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is, is that you are running into the fairly common `maxLength` bug that has been present in a number of modern browsers ([do a Google search about it](https://www.google.se/search?q=textarea%20maxlength%20bug&oq=textarea%20max&aqs=chrome.0.59l2j0j57j62l2.6501j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)).This is an example of how you could work around the problem, though not hardened for every situation (i.e. paste).

CSS

```
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<textarea id="myTextbox" maxlength="140" rows="4" cols="35"></textarea>
<div id="count">0</div>
<div id="alert" class="hidden">At max chars!</div>
<div id="newline" class="hidden">Newline prevented as it is 2 characters!</div>
```

Javascript

```
var myTextBox = document.getElementById('myTextbox'),
    count = document.getElementById('count'),
    alert = document.getElementById('alert'),
    newline = document.getElementById('newline'),
    maxLength = 140;

myTextBox.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    var value = e.target.value.replace(/\r?\n/g, '\r\n'),
        length = value.length;


    if (length >= maxLength) {
        if (length > maxLength) {
            length = maxLength - 1;
            e.target.value = value.slice(0, length);
            newline.classList.remove('hidden');
        } else {
            alert.classList.remove('hidden');
            newline.classList.add('hidden');
        }
    } else {
        alert.classList.add('hidden');
        newline.classList.add('hidden');
    }

    count.textContent = length;
}, false);
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/3NvKH/)

Comment: well that works in recent browsers
But business requiremets requires IE(

Comment: For older IEs that don't support `addEventListender` but use `attachEvent`, then you need to assign the event listener differently. Same with `classList`, you will need to add and remove classes with a polyfil/shim. Otherwise everything else is compatible. Search here on SO and you will find the information that you require. And instead of `input` you could use `keypress` or something similar that meets your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
function CheckSize(textBox, maxLength)
{
    if (textBox.value.length > maxLength)
    {
        alert("Max characters allowed are " + maxLength);
        textBox.value = textBox.value.substr(0, maxLength);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problems persists