# onkeyup and onkeydown on textarea to control maxlength

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, textarea, struts

I want to have a maxlength in textarea but html:textarea doesnt have the maxlength attribute. So I used the foll. code:

```
<html:textarea rows="5" cols="60" onkeyup="return imposeMaxLength(this, 50);" onkeydown="return imposeMaxLength(this, 50);" property="abc"></html:textarea>

function imposeMaxLength(Object, MaxLen)
    {
      return (Object.value.length <= MaxLen);
    }
```

This restricts the characters in the textarea to be < 50 but what happens is once you reach the limit(ie 50 in my case) the cursor is not functional. I cannot move cursor in the textarea. I mean i cannot delete the content or use backspace or do a ctrl+A and delete. The content remains unaltered or the textares content couldnt be changed. Is there any workaround to make it work or anyother suggestion?

Comment: Could you put up your `imposeMaxLength` function please?

Comment: That is not true in HTML5 it does have maxlength attribute.

Comment: @thatidiotguy Added the function

Comment: @ java.web "Attribute maxlength not defined in the element html:textarea" is what I get while adding maxlength attribute

Comment: @jave.web, The issue is an abstraction layer. Of course if he used <textarea..> rather than <html:textarea...> there would be no problem.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338997/check-size-of-multi-line-textbox/21339979#21339979 for some help

Comment: its jave.web, anyway you are not using HTML5 then :)

Comment: @JNPW can you use separate javascript?

Comment: @jave.web...using seperate JS? That is what i have done...???

Comment: @JNPW you are using the on keydown/up attributes - It would be better to use bind/addEventListener => then you could just check whether the key is arrows or backspace and if so => return true else=your current function

Comment: @jave.web...But i need to specify the keys right? When testers do regression testing they might come up with more scenarios and i need to handle each seperately.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with you approach it that you restrict any input after max length is reached. Might be better to slice the input to the size you want. Adding the event handlers is not necessary, but inline handlers in the html should be avoided.

```
var myTextarea = document.querySelector("#my-textarea");
var DEFAULT_MAX_LENGTH = 5;

function limitLength() {
  var maxLength = this.getAttribute("max-length") || DEFAULT_MAX_LENGTH;
  if (this.value.length > maxLength) {
    this.value = this.value.slice(0, maxLength);
  }
}

myTextarea.addEventListener("keydown", limitLength.bind(myTextarea));
myTextarea.addEventListener("keyup", limitLength.bind(myTextarea));
```

[Example Code on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3fN76poQD1INdZQE7dX2?p=info)

Comment: Slicing the value has really "bad" side effects since someone who moves the cursor at a position other than the end will continue to type LOSING the characters on the right most probably without knowing that it happens.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about your HTML syntax and floating JavaScript, but maybe that's just in your question.

In any event, at this point you cancel all keys once you reached the maximum length. What you want is leave the control keys alone. That includes the arrow keys, Ctrl-A, delete, backspace...

In your test, check the key first and if it is a special key, then always return true. Otherwise return the result of your current test. You can test with an alert() or a console.log() to see what the special key codes are:

```
console.log("Received key = " + Object.keycode);
```

The problem you'll have here also is that you're not using jQuery and this the "keycode" parameter is not going to work in all browsers. With jQuery you'd cancel the default propagation instead and use the event object the jQuery provides. It makes your code a lot easier/cleaner to handle such things.

P.S. I would avoid using the name "Object" for JavaScript variables. "Obj" would probably be safer.

Comment: Not using jQuery is not an issue, jQuery itself uses Javascript to get around compatability.

Comment: @Xotic750, oh I know, it's just that event.keycode is not going to work with all browsers...

Comment: Just a note so that the OP knows that jQuery is not a requirement but can make life easier at times (and more difficult at others). :)